# How can I get the insights corresponding to each optimization goal with the Meta API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I wish to get insights which correspond to each optimization goal - for example, `{'OPTIMIZATION_GOAL':['KPI1', 'KPI2', ...]}`.

However, this is proving difficult, since certain optimization goals (such as `VISIT_INSTAGRAM_PROFILE`) seemingly cannot be fetched via the Meta API, and certain others are confusing as to which KPIs correspond to them. That said, I noticed that the parameter can indeed be seen on the Ads Manager, under 'Results':

[Screenshot of Ads Manager, showing number of Instagram profile visits for a campaign containing two ad sets with VISIT_INSTAGRAM_PROFILE as their optimization goal under the 'Results' column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgFOo.png)

Is their a way to access this results parameter? Even better, is their a page on Meta's API that I haven't been able to find which points to an optimization_goal/insight mapping?

I've explored the documentation in [the insights page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/insights/), [the Action Stats page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/), and [the Ad Sets page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/), but `VISIT-INSTAGRAM-PROFILE` remains elusive. I'd appreciate a way to solve this without manually analyzing which KPIs correspond to each `optimization-goal`.